# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. flutter dart

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile-development

```
Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\****\StudioProjects\testing_app\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
   > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\****\StudioProjects\testing_app\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\****\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\c51ajzpii95tma58d2uea49kr).
      > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Zzu.png)